# Can a class containing virtual function made singleton?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Can a class containing virtual function made singleton?

Simply

```
class A:public B
{
   public:
   virtual fun();  //will be defined by this class (inherited from Class B)
}
```

Can i make this class singleton?

Comment: Certainly, why not? Why not try it first and see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking whether it's possible, then yes, of course, it is perfectly possible to create a singleton out of such a class.

If you're asking whether it makes sense, then the question is more difficult to answer; but mainly because singletons in general are a very disputed pattern. So you might want to ask yourself if you really need a singleton (singletons e.g. usually make testing much harder, you'd have to introduce special "workarounds" to get classes using them under test; basically, they're very thinly veiled global variables).

You'd also have to elaborate a bit on the intended use case: When you declare a method virtual, you basically say that some subclass may want to change that behavior. If the base class is a singleton, it means that there can only be one of it. Would the same have to apply for all subclasses? Should there be only ever one class derived from that one existing in your system? Then you'd best have a look at factories and possibly use them in conjunction with the Singleton (again, if you decide you *really need* the Singleton).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I was talking about possibility only. I need it as singleton but the virtual function that its containing is the function of Class B that is inherited by Class A and its behaviour will be defined in Class A which i need as a singleton class. There wont be any child class for the Class A.(no class will inherit Class A.)